# Альтернатива mysqli_ping. Как узнать статус соединения, не получив php warning?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть ***php cli процесс***, который может долгое время не обращаться к ***mysql***  и тогда ***mysql*** разорвет соединение, но в ***php*** об этом не узнают (*или все-таки узнают?*).
При следующей попытке получаю ошибку соединения, которую я отлавливаю и переоткрываю соединение

```
try {
  /* @var $s PDO instance */
  !$s->execute($params); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $s = db::connect();
}
```

но так же в лог ошибок я получаю бесполезный ***PHP Warning***, который будит меня по ночам.

***PDO*** согласно документации в режиме `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` выбрасывает исключения, но, как выяснилось, кроме того, он еще и генерирует ***PHP Warning*** (*проверено мной*).

**Вопрос**: Как не отключая глобально уровень ошибок ***PHP Warning*** (магическая `@` конечно же тоже не подходит), и не изменяя значение `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` избавиться от назойливого будильника?

Answer (score 1):

> Кроме того, он еще и генерирует PHP Warning

Насколько я знаю, это баг PDO (который будет вряд ли в ближайшее время исправлен, поскольку у PDO нет майнтайнера). Самое забавное, что изменение PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE на появление этой ошибки *не влияет*.

Так что надо искать обходные пути.

Я бы сказал, что использование собаки будет наименьшим из зол. Выбросу исключения она не помешает, а других возможных ошибок я придумать не могу.

Только я бы проверял соединение и пересоединялся не при выполнении запроса, а при получении соединения, в `db::connect();`, как это сделано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006338/285587). В любом случае, необходимо обязательно проверять, **какое именно исключение было брошено**, и пересоединяться только если соединение было сброшено. В противном случае, исключение должно быть перевыброшено. Если взять пример [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch), то получится что-то вроде

```
try {
    @self::$pdo->query("SELECT 1")->fetch();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if (strpos($e->getMessage(), "MySQL server has gone away") !== FALSE) {
        self::init();
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
return self::$pdo;
```

Comment: Да, у нас проверяется по коду (2006 если не ошибаюсь) и тогда идет реконнект, сильно упростил пример.  но вынос в получение соединения ничего не меняет, +1 лишний запрос на каждый get_connection.  Я считаю наш вариант более дешевым с точки зрения железа. Спасибо за ответ, пока что не помечаю вопрос решенным подожду может еще прилетят варианты решений.   По поводу бага - укажите пруф?.